# Is my OpenPGP key rubbish because of bad entropy?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, random, openpgp

I had problems generating an OpenPGP key on my XUbuntu machine, because GnuPG did not get enough entropy. After some time of browsing and doing stupid stuff to generate more entropy, still nothing happened.

So I followed an instruction and used rng tools:

```
sudo apt-get install rng-tools
sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom b
```

And voila, suddenly everything worked without any effort within a second. But how can that be? Did it just trick me and provided me pseudo random numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### rngd

[rngd's man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rngd) describes pretty well what the daemon is doing:

> This daemon feeds data from a random number generator to the kernel's random number entropy pool, after first checking the data to ensure that it is properly random.
>
> [...]
>
> The `-r` or `--rng-device` options can be used to select an alternate source of input, besides the default `/dev/hwrandom`.

To be specific, the command you ran extracted random numbers from `/dev/urandom` and passed it back into the Linux kernel's entropy pool while registering it as "real and fresh entropy", thus also making it available in `/dev/random` (this explanation is slightly simplified, and technically the process is a little bit more involved, but this is the idea behind the `rngd` call you posted).

Such tools are commonly used in virtual machines or embedded devices not receiving enough entropy to fill the entropy pool, as it does not have access to all entropy sources a "real hardware" computer would have (hard disk timing, ...).

### Random numbers in Linux

> And voila, suddenly everything worked without any effort within a second. But how can that be? Did it just trick me and provided me pseudo random numbers?

Yes, it did exactly this. Linux knows two random devices: `/dev/random` blocking when some rather arbitrary entropy counter decides not enough entropy is available, and `/dev/urandom` always returning new pseudo-random numbers. Now "pseudo-random number generator" sounds worse than it is, in fact random numbers from a (cryptographically robust, without bugs or backdoors) random number generator is not distinguishable from "real" random numbers. ["The plain simple reality of entropy -- Or how I learned to stop worrying and love urandom"](https://media.ccc.de/v/32c3-7441-the_plain_simple_reality_of_entropy) presented at 32C3 gives a great introduction in random number generators and why they are totally fine.

After all, also `/dev/random` is a random number generator with some rather arbitrary decision on whether the pool received enough random bits, and the even more arbitrary decision to decide it did not receive enough random bits recently.

Mixing in new entropy is not a bad idea anyway, just in case the mathematical foundations or software implementation have some issues -- new random bits (not coming from the entropy pool) will make breaking the random number pool much harder.

### Wrapup: Are the generated keys secure?

As always, the answer is: it depends. Given you already established a proper random state of the entropy pool by having the machine run for some time (ie., did not recently setup the system, but already used it for a longer time, with a few hours or days being more than safe for typical setups), the entropy pool was initialized properly and you have proper random numbers from now on, no matter if you feed back random numbers just to increase the Kernel's entropy counter.

All in all, the "not enough entropy" issues of GnuPG running on Linux is based on two debatable decisions: the Linux kernel providing `/dev/random` with it's arbitrary "I don't have enough random bits semantics", and GnuPG relying on this instead of `/dev/urandom`. Sadly, there is no way to choose another entropy source in GnuPG.